# IPhone - UIView addSubview Gap at top

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview

I have a view that is loaded in the MainWindow.xib.  It is just a view with a uiimageview in it that shows a image on the entire screen ( 320 X 480 ).  When the app loads I display this view and then I do a

```
[self.view addSubview:tabbarController.view];
```

Tab Bar Controller is just a UITabBarController with 2 View Controllers added to it.  When it adds the tabbarController's view to the subview it leaves a gap at the top of about 20px.  My app does have a status bar but this is basically room for another.  This happens unless I add this to my view controller:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Can anyone explain this.  I was doing

```
self.view = tabbarController.view;
```

but was told I shouldn't do that.  So now I'm adding a subview, but I don't understand why I have to adjust the CGRect of my view to not show the 20px.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

UITabBarController expects to have its view added as a subview of UIWindow, not as a subview of some other UIView.  The frame property defines the offset of the view within its superview, so the UITabBarController implementation offsets its view's frame by 20 pixels by default to leave room for the status bar.  You're using UITabBarController in a nonstandard way by adding it to a view that's already been offset by 20 pixels for the status bar.  UITabBarController offsets its view by an additional 20 pixels relative to its superview, causing the gap you see.

One clean way to fix this is add the UITabBarController's view as a subview of the window instead of a view:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:tabbarController.view];
```

(Note: The keyWindow method will only return your window if you've already called makeKeyAndVisible.  Otherwise, you may want to set a window property on your UIViewController.)

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation.  Maybe I should go back and restructure part of my app.  I want to do things the correct way, but I thought it may be better to separate the view controller logic from the app delegate - so my root view controller does all that it needs.  That would explain why in my root view controller if I did self.view = tabbarController.view instead of adding as a subview, I wouldn't get the gap.  Great answer.  I'd vote up more if I could.

Comment: It sounds like your instinct was good here.  This is just one of those design limitations in Cocoa Touch that we have to work around for now.  

Bear in mind though that you don't necessarily need add the tabbarController.view to your window from your app delegate.  You can add it in your view controller if that's where you think it makes the most sense.  You just need to have access to the window object, either via the keyWindow method, or by setting it as a property on your controller back in applicationDidFinishLaunching:.

Comment: but doesn't this mean that the tabbarcontroller.view is now a subview of the window.view?
But it's not correct in my case i have an ad view, and then a second contentview. And I'm adding the tabbarcontroller.view to the contentview. In this fashion the viewcontroller will handle the content/adview depending on ads. if i add the tabbarcontroller.view to the window, i don't think i'll be able to handle the views using my viewcontroller. what do you think?

Comment: The UITabBarController Class Reference says, "When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller."  I understand why you want tabbarcontroller.view to be a subview of a different view in your case.  Unfortunately you'd have to fight against the fact that this class adjusts its frames based on the assumption that its view is a subview of the window.  Consider using UITabBar in a custom UIViewController that implements UITabBarDelegate.

Comment: Interesting, how would I add 20px to a viewcontroller tab (child) of the UITabBarController to offset for the iOS7 status bar? Ive tried many SO solutions and none work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921062/how-to-apply-top-offset-for-status-bar-in-ios7-for-uitabbarcontroller-children-o