# How to apply top offset for status bar in iOS7 for UITabBarController children only

Tags: ios7, statusbar

My app is a UITabBarController based app with 3 children vc.  The status bar is overlapping with my viewcontrollers.  I have tried everything I have found in SO:

1. I tried adding this to my AppDelegate:

   //Offset downwards to make room for status bar
   self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);

It worked because it moved the entire UITabBarController down by 20.  But this resulted in the tabs being cut off at the bottom by -20.

So Im thinking i just want to apply the effect to the UIViewControllers in each tab since there is not much to cut off at the bottom.

2. So I tried adding similar code to the viewDidLoad and calling setNeedsDisplay afterwards:

   self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

But this has no effect at all, still get overlapping.

3. I tried adding this to viewDidLoad

   self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

and I also unchecked the Extend Edges Under Top Bars but it still runs into the status bar.  Also tried:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
 {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
 }
```

but no cigar.

4. I dont have the deltas because im using AL.
5. I dont want to HIDE my status bar because it displays open/close times so the user would find it handy to be able to see the time.

Im thinking shifting the view down a bit in each viewcontroller that needs it is the best option, but why didnt my code work for #2?

[image: Hierarchy]

(btw:not sure why code format isnt working and the numbering is off, even when i try to edit it, it seems to be working fine in the edit view but not in the pre-view or live-view)

Comment: Did you find the correct solution? chers

Answer (score 1):

for iOS 7 and xcode 5 to avoid overlapping

use in

viewDidLoad method

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the same problem as you.
I fixed it with many moves.
I use ruby motion:

```
@window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -20, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 20)
@window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height)
....
tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 20)
```

Let me know how it's going at your end.

update:
attach the screenshot:[image]

Comment: To anyone who has the same problem, my code works(the op might just ignore this answer).

Comment: I tried the above code,but it is not working. I added the TabBarController on UIWindow in Appdelegate.m

Comment: window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
tabController.selectedIndex = 0;
 window.rootViewController = tabController;
 [window addSubview:tabController.view];

    window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -20, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 20);
    window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
    tabController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 20);
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: It doesn't just depend on what iOSX you are building for.  It also depends what version your storyboard was created in. In this case, notice it was pre-xcode5 because it has no top or bottom layout guides. This makes a lot of the ios7/xcode5 code fixes NOT WORK.  It's not that Im ignoring an answer, its just not right! :)